# Part of my script stopped working once I merged it with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I stated using Wordpress and scripts that used to work do not work anymore on the website. Part of my script works just well, however another part doesn't work.

I have this so wordpress recognizes which libary I use.

```
 var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Here is part that **DOES WORK**: (no need to read/understand it)

```
  j(function() {
    j('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = j(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : j('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          j('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000);
          return false;
         }
       }
    });
 });
```

However this part of script **DOES NOT WORK**:

```
j('nav i').click(function(){
  j('nav ul').css('top','0');
  m_nav_on = true;
});

j('nav ul li').click(function(){
  if(m_nav_on === true){
    j('nav ul').css('top','-100%');
    m_nav_on = false;
  }
});

j('#content').click(function(){
  if(m_nav_on === true){
   j('nav ul').css('top','-100%');
  m_nav_on = false;
}
});
```

Both worked just fine until I used it in my custom wordpress theme. Anyone know the issue? As much as I see, .click(function(){}) part does not work.

Comment: Are there any console errors? Some variables might be undefined and it's throwing errors.

Comment: There are no console errors. In fact there are no syntax errors at all because I have this code at the start of script:
     j(window).load(function() {
      j(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
Which does not remove loading screen until everything is loaded just fine.
})

Comment: did you place code in document ready?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I added scripts into wordpress this way: function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' );

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? nav is class?

Comment: No I am not using Bootstrap. Nav is HTML5 element <nav></nav>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first scripts (which are working) are contained within a `ready` function...`j(function(){ // stuff });`. The second scripts aren't contained in a ready function, and are being enqueued in the `<head>` of your document. This means that the elements which you are attaching `click` handlers to don't yet exist.

You have two options:

1. Enqueue these scripts in the footer of your document
2. Wrap the `click` handlers in a `ready` function.

An example of option #2:

```
j(function(){
    m_nav_on = false;  // Add a default value

    j('nav i').click(function(){
      j('nav ul').css('top','0');
      m_nav_on = true;
    });

    j('nav ul li').click(function(){
      if(m_nav_on === true){
        j('nav ul').css('top','-100%');
        m_nav_on = false;
      }
    });

    j('#content').click(function(){
      if(m_nav_on === true){
        j('nav ul').css('top','-100%');
        m_nav_on = false;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Also important to note...unless I'm missing something, you should be checking if `m_nav_on` is both `defined` and `true`...In your second and third click handlers, it's possible that `m_nav_on` hasn't even been defined...You can also add a default to prevent this issue.

Comment: A very good answer, it worked. And it is really well explained.